# Activating standby DR after opening it in read-write mode

Tags: oracle, standby

I have a primary and a standby database. Both two node RAC database.

As some testing had to be done in standby database, I had to open it in read-write mode.

I cancelled the recovery in standby and activated standby database and opened the two node database in read-write mode.

Now, the DR is broken. And to make the standby as a proper physical standby, full reconfiguration of DR is required?

If not, help me out in setting up my standby back in track!

Answer (score 1):

If you had flashback enabled or created a restore point before activating the standby database, you can flashback the database to that point/SCN, and the standby database can continue from there like nothing happened.

You can do this manually, or if you have Data Guard Broker configured, you can use the `REINSTATE DATABASE` command to do this.

In case you have not prepared for this, you will need to rebuild (duplicate/restore) the standby database.

Next time do not do this, there is a feature called [Snapshot Standby](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SBYDB/manage_ps.htm#SBYDB4801) designed for testing tasks like this, that works just as I described above.